# why you need to explicitly import spring-security-web dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

In a sample Spring project with the following security config:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MySimpleEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("admino")).roles("USER","ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder.encode("123456")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public MySimpleEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new MySimpleEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I noticed  that you need these two dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but also this, which is needed at runtime:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Why isn't the last dependency automatically pulled with runtime scope by one of the other two dependencies?

Why do we need to explicitly declare it?

I'm using Spring 5

Comment: because dependencies should not be tightly coupled with other ones

Comment: Maybe there is also security for non web applications and if you pull all These dependeies you can run in different problems

Comment: Using Spring Initializr when you include security module, you get https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security. Maybe try this one.

Comment: @J.Kennsy I actually want to declare explicitly the dependencies I'm directly using, so that dependency:analyze is happy.

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Security** is a different module of Spring.
This module is not being used always where we use ***Spring Core*** or ***Spring Web***/ ***Spring MVC*** or any other module.
This is a independent module, whenever needed we can add and use.

This is the reason Spring developers made **Spring Security module independent**.

We should not make our application heavy with unused stuff.
We should use that when application demands.

Answer (score 0):

The framework is that huge itself that it has even its own framework called [Spring-Boot](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot). It makes perfect sense to separate functional parts into something called [Spring Projects](https://spring.io/projects). There are lots of official ones the same as the community projects: Few examples:

- Spring Data
- Spring Security
- Spring Batch

Note the Spring webpage notes:

> Spring is modular by design

Learning all Spring Projects could get cumbersome and overwhelming. The same you divide your application into packages, projects - the same approach uses Spring to control all its parts independently on others. Some Spring Projects are still too big enough to be divided into Subprojects - Spring Security is a good example of this.

Comment: So you think it is ok to be forced to declare that runtime dependency ourselves ? can this be a minor flaw ?

Comment: A Runtime dependency is copied into your deployed application and is available on the unit test execution and runtime execution, but it is not available during compilation. I see no problem with `runtime`.